# about lipid oxidation, does acid fatty transforms in glucose?

Tags: biochemistry, glucose, lipids

Lipid oxidation generates fatty acid and glycerol going into the bloodstream.

Can they be converted into glucose by gluconeogenesis or are they turnd into ketone bodies?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the tour and read how to ask questions before posting.  You will see that you are required to demonstrate the attempt you have made to answer the question yourself. This question has been asked and answered before on this list and generally on the internet.

Comment: My english is very bad. Can't you give me the article?